# VS2017 - Error adding mobile apps table controller - Error HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3, I try to add a Mobile App Table Controller but I received the next Error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBIDL.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed in the new version  15.4.1

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts9oM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on 15.3.5 as well.

There was a similar error when creating Table Controller on 15.2.

And on 15.3.2, it was OK to create Table Controller.

I think this is a Microsoft's bug, like what they have done again and again.

You can still create Table Controller (it is C# code with some settings) manually as said in

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/68503/cant-add-a-mobile-app-table-controller.html

Comment: I think the same, it´s a Microsoft's bug, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can also add a reference to System.Data and it will work. I ran into this issue, too.